# Unable to get routes working in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, routes

The server.js code is this one after running the  node server.js command 
i am able to access the http://localhost:8080/ and getting the json correctly

```
{"error":false,"data":[{"id":1,"task":"Find bugs","status":1,"created_at":"2016-04-10T18:20:40.000Z"},{"id":2,"task":"Review code","status":1,"created_at":"2016-04-10T18:20:40.000Z"},{"id":3,"task":"Fix bugs","status":1,"created_at":"2016-04-10T18:20:40.000Z"},{"id":4,"task":"Refactor Code","status":1,"created_at":"2016-04-10T18:20:40.000Z"},{"id":5,"task":"Push to prod","status":1,"created_at":"2016-04-10T18:20:50.000Z"}],"message":"Todos list."}
```

but when i try to access the http://localhost:8080/secret i am getting "Cannot GET /secret " error. My server.js file is this one

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended:true 
}));
const mc = mysql.createConnection({
host:'localhost',
user : 'root',
password : '',
database : 'task'
});
mc.connect();

// Retrieve all todos 

//default route
app.all('/',function(req,res,next){

     mc.query('SELECT * FROM tasks', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        return res.send({ error: false, data: results, message: 'Todos list.' });
        next()
    });
     });
 app.use('/secret', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Accessing the secret section ...')
  next() // pass control to the next handler
})
app.listen(8080,function(){

    console.log('Node app is running on port 8080');
});
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation right now seems incomplete. You should check out the [express.Router documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) (check out the very bottom of the page).

The `use` method you are trying to use should include at least a `router.get('/', function (req, res) {} );` implementation. Alternatively, you could replace `use` with `get` or `all` and it would work.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should use get instead of all, and the next function is not required. try the below method.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    mc.query('SELECT * FROM tasks', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        return res.send({ error: false, data: results, message: 'Todos list.' });
    });
});
```